# Areas - Como fazer aparecer um diretório antes de Controller/Action/ na rota?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aplicação-web, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

Olá.

Criei um projeto Web *ASP.NET MVC Core* no *Visual Studio 2019* e Criei uma area chamada Gerencial. Dentro dela, na pasta Views eu criei uma subpasta chamada Produtos e coloquei algumas views lá dentro.

Minhas rotas estão assim:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Produtos}/{action=index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

A estrutura de pastas está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que na url do browser aparecesse:

> localhost:{porta}//Gerencial/Produtos/(cadastrar por exemplo)

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi.

Usei a seguinte rota:

```
routes.MapAreaRoute(
                name: "areas",
                areaName: "Gerencial",
                template: "Gerencial/{controller=Produtos}/{action=index}/{id?}");
```

A URL ficou do jeito que eu queria.
Se alguém quiser acrescentar algo eu agradeço.